# PHP PDO - Update in mysql only posted value (html form)

Tags: php, forms, pdo

I have an html form that has some disabled field depending of what kind of authorization the user have. When I press submit, the script should understand which form field are posted and which not, and then update only the related field in the database.

For example:

I can modify `Birthday`, `Birth place` and `sex`, but `Name` and `Surname` are disabled and so are not posted by the html form. Therefore have to be updated only `Birthday`, `BirthPlace`, `Sex` where `id = $idperson`. But if I have permission, I post `Name` and `Surname` too. And therefore I should update also these value.

Is there a fast way to do it with PDO? Or I have to create a long sequence of if/else?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You should be able to loop through the `$_POST` to create a query string + the bind array.

Comment: Alternately, you could probably make a class that will build these as well using a similar method.

Answer (score 0):

The Best and easy way to do this,

- First collect post data and check id is set
- fetch all data from your table using id
- loop your post data and check with collected details
- if collected details value and post value changed update in collected details variable
- update all your fields with new collected array

Check the below code for more understanding

```
function collect() {
   if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
      // validate id and get all details from table
      $details = getDetails($_POST['id']);
      foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        // loop your post data and check with collected details if value changed update in collected details 
         if(array_key_exists($key, $details)) {
            $details[$key] = ($details[$key] != $_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$Key] : $details[$key];
         }
      }
   } else {
      echo "id not found to update";
   }
}

function getDetails($id) {
   $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=:id";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
   $stmt->execute();
   return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}


function update($details) {
   $query = "UPDATE table_name SET field_1=:field_1, field_2=:field_2, all_field=:all_field WHERE id=:id";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare();
   $stmt->bindParam(':field_1', $details['field_1']);
   ...
   $stmt->bindParam(':id', $details[$id]);
   return $stmt->execute();
}
```

Hope this code helps you, Happy coding.